# Display a Set of Objects in JSP page, with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new in spring mvc and jstl, and  i want to display a set of objects in my jsp page, that are my two classes :

```
Class Phase{
 private Set<Tache> taches;
}

Class Tache{
 private String name;
} 

Class Controller{
 @RequestMapping(value="/pages/index")
public  String pageProject(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("phaseList", phaseService.getAllPhases());
 return "/pages/createProject";
}

Class PhaseDAO{
 @Override
public List<Phase> getAllPhases() {
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    return session.createQuery("from Phase").list();
}
}
Class PhaseService{
@Transactional
public List<Phase> getAllPhases() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return phaseDao.getAllPhases();
}
}
```

And in my JSP :

```
j:forEach items="phaseList" var="phase" <br>
    ${phase.taches} <br>
/j:forEach
```

So i want to display in a jsp page Taches per Phase.

Please help me !

Comment: What does `phaseList` contains or what do you return from  `getAllPhases()` ?

Comment: getAllPhases() return a Set of Phases that stored in the database

Comment: You could print it as `phase` simply from your edited question

Comment: Are you sure that `phaseList` is not Null . If it is not null then print like this `${phase}` instead of `${phase.taches}`

Comment: it display this : com.model.Phase@689574 ___ I think that i have to make two loops, the first to display the name of phase and the second the taches (tasks) with there names that belong to this phase.. But i don't know how..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of Phases. Each phase has a list of Taches. Simple logic would suggest you need two loops:

```
<c:forEach var="phase" items="${phaseList}">
    <c:forEach var="tache" items="${phase.taches}">
        <tr>
            <td>${tache.name}</td>
        </tr> 
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example getting list of objects in jsp and dispaly

```
<c:forEach var="object" items="${phaseList}">

                            <tr>
                            <td> <c:out value="${status.attribute}"/></td>
                        </tr> 
                        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: That's what i did, but it doesn't work, it just print in page something like this [], i want to display the name of taches per phase: 
Example :

Phase1 :
Tache1 name : Survey 
Tache2 name : QOS

Phase2:
Tache1 name : MS
...

Comment: check two things   1- phaseList has data 2-you are using correct attribute in for each loop . That's it

Comment: Yes it has data because when i display the name of phase, it work correctly... But not the name of the taches that belong to this phase